# How do I get a Proc Compare output that ONLY shows the differences between obs as well as the actual observation taken from both the BASE and COMPARE?

Tags: sas, compare, output, proc

I want to create a dataset that shows the values produced by OUTBASE and OUTCOMP but only for observations with unequal values. Is there a way to do this?

So essentially I am trying to have 3 rows for each unequal observation = the difference (DIF), the base observation (BASE), and the compare observation (COMP).

For example, say I had the following:

```
**BASE**
ID | Age | Sex |
ID_01 | 24 | Male  |
ID_02 | 45 | Female |
ID_03 | 66 | Female |

**COMPARE**
ID | Age| Sex |
ID_01 | 25 | Female |
ID_02 | 45 | Female |
ID_03 | 69 | Female |
```

I want the output to look like the following:

```
type | ID | Age | Sex |

BASE | ID_01 | 24 | Male |
COMPARE | ID_01 | 25 | Female |
DIF | ..... | 1 | XXXXXX |

BASE | ID_03 | 66 | Female |
COMPARE | ID_03 | 69 | Female |
DIF | ..... | 3 | ...... |
```

It would exclude ID_02 as they are identical in both BASE and COMPARE. Thus, it only shows the observations that have differences. It also shows the DIF, BASE, and COMPARE obs.

So far I have only been able to get the output dataset to show either:

1. the actual difference between base and compare but not the actual base and compare observations as well
2. the differences between base and compare as well as the actual base and compare observations, however, for all observations, not just unequal ones

Code I've tried:

```
proc compare base = pre_upd.pre_update 
             compare = post_upd.post_update 
             out = results.results 
             outnoequal; 
id subj_recpos;
run;
```

Comment: Are you looking for this in the displayed output or the data set output? Have you tried the `outnoequal` option and the output data set method? Also, please show your code to indicate what you've tried and provide data as a data step. .

Comment: Hi Reeza. Yes I have used outnoequal with and without other 'out' options to no avail. See below for the proc compare code:

Comment: proc compare base = pre_upd.pre_update 
                       compare = post_upd.post_update
                out = results.results
                       outnoequal;

             id subj_recpos;
run;

Comment: And yes, in the data set output (excel).

Comment: If you can edit your question to include the code in the future and sample data as I've done below that will help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work fine for me.

If you run the following do you get the expected results?
If not, try adding the FUZZ option (included in the code below).

```
data have;
infile cards dlm='|' truncover;
input ID $ Age  Sex $;
cards;
ID_01 | 24 | Male  |
ID_02 | 45 | Female |
ID_03 | 66 | Female |
;

data compare;
infile cards dlm='|' truncover;
input ID $ Age  Sex $;
cards;
ID_01 | 25 | Female |
ID_02 | 45 | Female |
ID_03 | 69 | Female |
;

proc compare base = have compare = compare out = results outnoequal outbase outcompare outdif fuzz=0.1; 
id ID; 
run;

proc print data=results;
run;
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the response, much appreciated. I've tried running that code but again it only gives 1 row for each ID with unequal values, which is the DIF. I am also looking to output the original row of data for the base ('have' in this case) and the compare (compare).

Comment: Essentially, I want the output to have 3 rows per observation that has unequal values. The DIF (like the one outputted from your code), but also the original base and compare observations. It is so I can clearly see what was in the original base and what was in the original compare, instead of seeing DIF alone. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: See the updates - add the different OUT options.

Comment: Use OUTALL if you want the percent difference as well.